# Is there a word for someone who gets hyper while angry?

Tags: single-word-requests

In this specific sense, I'm looking for a descriptor word (or title, whatever, I can shape a sentence to fit whatever kind of word it is) that would be for someone who tends to be energized by anger. 
For example, someone who is prone to pacing quickly or flailing their arms when provoked to anger.

Comment: One could (depending on the audience) make allusions to [The Incredible Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_(comics)).

Comment: *anger-excitable*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good word for this is [apoplectic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apoplectic) (MW, defined for language learners)

> very angry and excited

The literal definition of this is 'of, relating to, or causing stroke', but other than in the medical field, it's used as above in a more metaphoric sense.  There are several example sentences in the above link, such as:

> The coach was so apoplectic when the player missed the free throw that he threw his clipboard onto the court.

Answer (score 0):

How about "manic?" One definition of the word (from [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/manic)) is as follows:

> **manic** *adjective* ... **1.1** showing wild and apparently deranged excitement and energy.

Comment: Please mention the name and link to the dictionary.

Comment: I added a source credit to a dictionary that contains the cited language, and linked to the relevant page of that dictionary (in case you were uncertain about how to create such links at this site). Please adopt a similar approach in your future answers at English Language & Usage. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In such a situation, you can say that the person gets [***hopping mad***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hopping+mad).

> very angry; angry and jumping up and down. *I was hopping mad about the broken window.*

(Mc-Graw Hill)